# Error when deploying serverless application in python

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, serverless, serverless-framework

After I signed in in my `serverless account` and then I tried to deploy my application (on Amazon),
it shows me this error

```
    Error: `docker run --rm -v C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/3c5307946d60c3cf6dcd718de08a5ac453454387e6a435435edf993f360200a547cc_x86_64_slspyc:/var/task:z -v C:/Users/user/AppDa
ta/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/downloadCacheslspyc:/var/useDownloadCache:z -u 0 lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 python -m pip install -t /var/task/ -r /var/task/requirements.txt --cache-dir /var/useDownload
Cache` Exited with code 1
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\voice-reckognition\node_modules\child-process-ext\spawn.js:38:8)
      at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
      at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\user\Desktop\voice-reckognition\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
      at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
```

My application is with python and I have installed `serverless-python-requirements` and it is my `package.json` like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "serverless-python-requirements": "^5.3.0"
  }
```

Also in my `serverless.yml`, I have those:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements


custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
```

How to solve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using *serverless framework* to deploy ,based on the documentation when you want to install the **serverless-python-requirements** you have to use this line on the terminal first `serverless plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements`. This will automatically add the plugin to your project's package.json and the plugins section of it's serverless.yml. You do not have to do this manually as you can make any mistake in the process.

Comment: The error messages showing `docker run` means `serverless-python-requirements` was already installed used being used.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says `docker run` failed: `Exited with code 1` -- were there more error message printed?

Make sure that `docker` is working on your system. I needed to reboot after installing docker (I think there was a permission problem with the SSH session that was running before change to docker group was made), and then the next `serverless deploy` worked without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this error countless times, and it's always because `docker` isn't running on my system when I try to deploy. Error message is not terribly direct about that one.